# Want to store a string into a file, with the filename being the output of a command in shell

Tags: linux, shell

I want to store a string in a file and the name of the file is the concatenation of the output of the whoami command and the output of filename="date +'%D-%H-%M'". currently I am doing something like

```
user=$whoami
echo "Sample String" > $user
```

But it is not working. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Also, as I mentioned above I want to concat the output of the $user and $filename as the final name of the file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
name="$(date +'%d%m%Y-%H-%M')_$(whoami)"
echo "Sample string" >> $name
```

Then we have:

```
$ ls -ltr
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me    6 Jun 24 17:00 24062013-17-00_me
```

Your

```
user=$whoami
```

was not working because it should be `user=$(whoami)`. In general, to store a command output you have to do `variable=$(command)`.

Comment: @anonymous123: You can mark above answer as accepted answer, thereby closing this question...